# How can I import all unimported classes in Scala IDE?

Tags: eclipse, scala, keyboard-shortcuts, import, scala-ide

When I use Java with Eclipse and write a class, sometimes I have to import classes. The fastest way to do that is with a keyboard shortcut: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>O</kbd>. But this keyboard shortcut seem to be broken in [Scala IDE](http://www.scala-ide.org/). It opens an empty "Refactoring" popup instead.

Is there a keyboard shortcut for importing all unimported classes in Scala IDE?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Our current implementation of Organize Imports doesn't add missing imports, it only reorganizes the existing ones and removes unneeded ones. I'm currently working on an improved version, and adding missing imports is also on my agenda.

In the meantime, we already have a quickfix that you can use to import a single missing import.

Comment: Sounds good. Is there a keyboard shortcut for the single missing import?

Comment: Ctrl+1, but the caret needs to be on the same line as the missing import, otherwise it won't work.